# Trouble proving that a plane in (synthetic) projective space containing two points must contain the line between them

Tags: projective-geometry, axiomatic-geometry

I'm working through Hartshorne's *Foundations of Projective Geometry*, and have hit a sticking point with problem 7(a). For clarity, I'll reproduce the axiom system presented for projective 3-space:

1. Two points determine a unique line.
2. Three non-collinear points determine a unique plane.
3. Any line intersects any plane in at least one point.
4. Any two planes intersect in at least one line.*
5. There exist four non-coplanar points, with no three among them collinear.
6. Every line has at least three points.

*Note that if we have two planes, their intersection contains some line $l$ by this axiom, and by axiom 6 that line has some points on it, say $S$ and $T$. If the intersection also contained $U \notin l$, then both planes would contain $S,T,U$ non-collinear, and would thus have to be equal by axiom 2; therefore, in these axioms, we still have that *two distinct planes intersect in exactly one line.*

Problem 7(a) then asks the reader to prove:

"If two distinct points $P$, $Q$ lie in a plane $\Sigma$ then the line joining them is contained in $\Sigma$."

Here's an attempted proof, and what goes wrong with it.

*Proof.* Let $P, Q \in \Sigma$. **There must exist a point $R$ which is neither in $\Sigma$ nor in the line $PQ$.** But then $PQR \cap \Sigma$ is exactly a line by above, and that line must be $PQ$ since both planes contain the points $P$ and $Q$. Therefore $\Sigma$ contains $PQ$.

The statement in bold doesn't feel justifiable---there certainly has to be a point outside of $\Sigma$ by axiom 5, but what precludes the possibility that *all* points outside of $\Sigma$ happen to lie on $PQ$? Or, is there a better approach that I'm just not seeing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take any distinct points $P,Q$ on any plane $S$. Let $A,B,C,D$ be non-coplanar points such that no three of them are collinear. Then not all of $A,B,C,D$ are on $S$. By symmetry we can assume that $A$ is not on $S$. Let $T$ be a plane containing $P,Q,A$. Then $S ≠ T$. Let $L = S∩T$. Let $X,Y$ be distinct points on $L$. Then $P,X,Y$ are contained in both $S,T$. If $P$ is not on $L$, then $P,X,Y$ are contained within a unique plane, contradicting $S ≠ T$. Thus $P$ is on $L$. Symmetrically, $Q$ is on $L$. Thus $P,Q$ are contained in both $PQ,L$. Thus $PQ = L$.

[Edit: It was pointed out that it's not so simple if $P,Q,A$ are collinear, so here is how we can deal with that special case. Let $E$ be a point not on $PA$. Let $U$ be a plane containing $P,A,E$. Then by the same reasoning as above we have $PA = S∩U$. Similarly let $V$ be a plane containing $Q,A,E$, and then $QA = S∩V$. Thus $PA$ is contained in both $U,V$. If $U ≠ V$, then $PA = U∩V = AE$ (with second equality by the same reasoning again), yielding contradiction. Therefore $U = V$ and that plane contains $P,Q,A$.]

By the way, [using bare "let" is not a good idea when it conflates ∃elim with ∀subcontext-reasoning (i.e. reasoning about an arbitrary *given* object of a stipulated type)](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/18155/1550).

Comment: To be clear, the step "Let $L=S∩T$." relies on your note that there is a unique line contained within any two distinct planes $S,T$, and this uniqueness allows us to call this line *the* intersection of $S,T$. If you want to completely reduce to the axioms, then you just have to expand the proof of your note at that point in my proof.

Comment: I see! The step where you pick $T$ was completely invisible to me---I was worried that somehow you wouldn't be able to find any $T$ if $P, Q, A$ are collinear, but of course you can just take any point $B$ not on $PQ$ if that happens. Thanks very much!

Comment: You write "Let $T$ be a plane containing $P,Q,A$." If they are not collinear, $T$ is guaranteed to exist by axiom 2. How do you know that three collinear points are contained in at least one plane?

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger: Does my edit fix the gap?